# Multiply value of text fields with the same class dynamically using another input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have the following form that is created on the fly using Coldfusion. The different inputs all have different values when loaded, but share the same class.

I will have another input field with a unique identifier - #permup

The form is as follows (form tag stripped):

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="county-table" style="margin-top: 15px;">

<tr>
<TD>Length</TD>
<TD align="center">PerM</TD>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">

<TD>from 1-10m</TD>
<TD align="center"><input class="perm" type="text" name="PerM1" value="1.60"  size="6" /></TD>

</tr>



<tr bgcolor="#efefef">

<TD>from 11-20m</TD>
<TD align="center"><input class="perm" type="text" name="PerM2" value="1.10"  size="6" /></TD>

</tr>



<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">

<TD>from 21-50m</TD>
<TD align="center"><input class="perm" type="text" name="PerM3" value="1.50"  size="6" /></TD>

</tr>



<tr bgcolor="#efefef">

<TD>from 51-80m</TD>
<TD align="center"><input class="perm" type="text" name="PerM4" value="1.55"  size="6" /></TD>


</tr>



<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">

<TD>from 81-150m</TD>
<TD align="center"><input class="perm" type="text" name="PerM5" value="1.10"  size="6" /></TD>


</tr>



<tr bgcolor="#efefef">

<TD>from 151-200m</TD>
<TD align="center"><input class="perm" type="text" name="PerM6" value="1.10"  size="6" /></TD>


</tr>



<tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input id="permup" type="text" name="permup" value="0"  size="6" /></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

What I need is that when someone types the base rate increase in the #permup field, the fields with the class .perm have all their values increased by that amount, and if someone then sets the #permup field to 0 (zero) the fields with .perm are set back to their original value.

This has to work with JQuery on the class name as the table rows could be any number. I have the following script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

$('#permup').keyup( function() { 

    $('.perm').each(function(){

        var defaultValue = $(this).val();

        $(this).val( $('#permup').val() * defaultValue );

    });

});

</script>
```

It kind of works, but sets every value the same in the .perm fields and also does weird stuff when the field #perm is clicked out of or set to zero.

I hope someone can help!!

Many thanks

JS

Comment: Make sure you ensure that you actually have numbers before you try to do math.

Comment: I don't see a place where you define a default value either. That could be the issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try using `parseFloat()` and use `keyup` and `focus` event as shown :-

```
$('#permup').on('keyup focus', function() {
   $('.perm').each(function(){
      var defaultval = $('#permup').val();
      var myValue;
      if(defaultval == "0"){ 
        myValue = $(this).attr('value') 
       }
      else{
        myValue = parseFloat( parseFloat($(this).attr('value')) * parseFloat(defaultval) ) || $(this).attr('value')
       }
       $(this).val( myValue );
   });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9mduhew/1/)

**Side Note :-** Always try to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` while dealing in numbers in **javascript/jquery** otherwise **numbers** are also treated as **string**.

Comment: What does parseInt("25A7") return?

Comment: Thanks for the time to look at this! Sorry for the late reply but for some reason not getting the notifications! This almost works - however, when I enter 2 in the #permup field, it does as it should, however if I delete the 2 and decide I need them all multiplied by 4, then the new calculation is 4*the value arrived when entering 2! What I mean is if a field has the initial value of 10, I enter 2 in the #permup and the value is 20 (all good), however if I then decide that  I want to increase by 4 actually, the value is 80, not 40 (4*ORIGINAL value of the box). Does that make sense? Thanks

Comment: Minus 1.  <script>document.write("hello " + parseInt("123A4") + "  " + parseFloat("123A4") + " goodby");</script> returns hello 123 123 goodby.  Unlike @Kartikeya, I actually tested it.

Comment: @JanSolo..and if you  want to reduce decimal places than use .toFixed(2) at last when you are setting textbox value.

Comment: That is fantastic - thank you very much for taking the time to solve this for me - I was going round in circles!!

Comment: @JanSolo...hahaha....great..happy to help you.. and do upvote this good answer when you got required reputation... don't understand why someone downvoted this answer with no reason.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you need to make sure you are doing math with numbers and not the default "value" given by the .value property. Also it is not advisable to store values in your display as you run into issues on how to retrieve an old value once you modify it. Below is code that does what you want and keeps track of the original values.

```
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


   // Store default values
   var perm_items = document.getElementsByClassName("perm");
   var orig_perm_values = new Array(perm_items.length);

   for (var i = perm_items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    orig_perm_values[i] = perm_items[i].value;

    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = orig_perm_values[i];
  }


     function updateValues(event)
  {   
     for (var i = perm_items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     {
        perm_items[i].value = (parseFloat(orig_perm_values[i]) + parseFloat(event.target.value)).toFixed(2);
     }
  }   

  </script>
```